# ControllerContext throwing error in Parallel.ForEach in mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have function which return string and it has parameter of ControllerContext and this is throwing error

Here is code

```
        var cContext = ControllerContext;

       Parallel.ForEach(listInvHeaderIDs, x =>         
       {

        body = new myClass().myFunctionReturnString(cContext);

       }
```

Can we use **ControllerContext** in Parallel.Foreach if not than what to use

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Is `ControllerContext` even thread safe?

Comment: error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score -1):

You can probably try this overload of the `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
public static ParallelLoopResult ForEach<TSource, TLocal>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
      Func<TLocal> localInit, Func<TSource, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal> body,
      Action<TLocal> localFinally)
```

> Executes a `foreach` operation with thread-local data on an `IEnumerable` in which iterations may run in parallel, and the state of the loop can be monitored and manipulated.

An example of usage:

**UDPATE**
I've updated the example, should be ok now.

```
Parallel.ForEach(listInvHeaderIDs, () => {return cContext; }, 
(listId, loopInfo, ctrlContext) =>            
{
    body = new myClass().myFunctionReturnString(ctrlContext);
    return ctrlContext;
}, 
(ctrlContext) => { /*access controller context if needed...*/} );
```

Comment: Without seeing what error OP is seeing, this answer is pure speculation.

Comment: Its giving error Delegate 'Action<int>' does not take 0 argument